# Setar cor da fonte em célula no BrOffice

Tags: delphi

Exporto dados de um relatório para uma planilha eletrônica, dependendo do que o usuário tiver instalado na máquina, para `Excel` ou para o `BrOffice`.
Minha dúvida está ao colorir a fonte de uma célula no `BrOffice`, sei que tenho de usar o código `.CharColor := clBlue` por exemplo.
Mas pelo resultado que obtive, é necessário fazer alguma conversão para a cor resultante ser a que desejo.
Fazendo como no exemplo, ao invés do texto na planilha ficar em *Azul*, ficou em *Vermelho*. Esse foi só um exemplo, mas aconteceu em todas as células e com outras cores.

A dúvida é: Existe uma tabela de conversão? Ou como contorno essa situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente é necessário converter a cor, tente com esta função:

```
function SwapColor(nColor: TColor): TColor;
var
  c1, c2, c3: byte;
begin
  c1 := (nColor and $000000FF);        // $..0000FF
  c2 := (nColor and $0000FF00) shr 8;  // $..00FF00
  c3 := (nColor and $00FF0000) shr 16; // $..FF0000

  result := (c1 shl 16) + (c2 shl 8) + c3;
end;
```

Dê uma olhada nesses links:

http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/artigo/162/delphi-e-openoffice(broffice)---parte-3
https://github.com/sergio-hcsoft/Delphi-SpreadSheets

Comment: Conversão perfeita! Muito obrigado.